# Create a function for Social Security Number Swift

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I'm trying to create a function that makes the user write their Social Security number, in Parse, Like this: YYMMDD-XXXX

Here is my code:

```
func isValidBirth() -> Bool {
    let birthEX = "[00-99]+@[1-12]+@[1-31]+\\-[0000-9999]"
    let range = birthField!.rangeOfString(birthEX, options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
    let result = range != nil ? true : false
    return result
}
```

Every time I try to Sign Up, I get this error that I have not written my Social Security Number right.

I think I have created this function wrong due to I'm still a beginner. :)

How do I create a function that makes USER write their Social Security Number? Or if I now have done right, why is it not working?

Comment: This is confusing. The title and question talk about SSN. But the pattern in the 1st paragraph is not SSN and the code is about email. Where's your code related to checking SSN? BTW - I'm assuming you are talking about SSN in the USA with the format XXX-XX-XXXX.

Comment: Sorry, I miss copied the wrong function. Well, I found a tutorial on how to make E-mails be written exactly how you want them to be, so I thought could implement the same method on the Social Security Number-part.

Comment: Is your question asking what the regular expression needs to be? And again, what format do you really want? The `YYMMDD-XXX` or `XXX-XX-XXXX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify one thing: what you want is not US-style social security number. SSN in US contains no birthday. I interpret it to mean that you want to create your own SSN scheme, or that of another country.

Anyhow, don't expect the regex engine to understand `[00-99]` as "00 to 99". The square bracket means "match any of the characters inside". This is how regex interpret it:

```
[
    0     - match the character 0; or
    0-9   - match any character 0 to 9; or
    9     - match the character 9
]
```

So in the end, that is equivalent to `[0-9]`. You need to modify the regex pattern:

```
func isValidBirth(str: String) -> Bool {
    let birthEx = "\\d{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[1-2]\\d|3[0-1])-\\d{4}"
    let range = str.rangeOfString(birthEx, options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
    return range != nil
}

isValidBirth("920101-1234") // true
isValidBirth("120231-4321") // true, but this is Feb 31 !!!
isValidBirth("151120-123")  // false
```

About the regex pattern:

```
\\d{2}                      - the year: any 2 digits
(0[1-9]|1[0-2])             - the month: 01 - 09, or 10 - 12
(0[1-9]|[1-2]\\d|3[0-1])    - the day: 01 - 09, 10 - 29, or 30 - 31
-                           - the literal dash character
\\d{4}                      - any four-digit number
```

There are some obvious caveats: (1) when you write year in 2-digit format, the exact year is ambiguous. `15` can be `1915` or `2015`; (2) it doesn't validate the day, meaning Feb 31 is a valid day.

Comment: I Salute to you my friend! =)

Comment: `guard isValidBirth() else {
        
            throw Error.InvalidBirth
        }
`

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, Getting the error "Missing error for parameter #1 in call". What does it mean?